# Python "Invalid To header" when sending mail with drafts id

Tags: gmail-api

I want to send e-mails that I saved as drafts with Python. But I have an issue with the following error

> raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts/send?alt=json returned "Invalid To header". Details: "[{'message': 'Invalid To header', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalidArgument'}]">"

This is how I send it

```
s1=service.users().drafts().send(userId='me', body={ 'id': 's:7341000979429260348' })
```

I think I did everything right but I am facing this error.

Comment: welcome to stack please edit your question and include [example].   However i think the error **Invalid To header** may give you a clue that there's something wrong with one of the headers you are sending.

Comment: Please share your request.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo s1=service.users().drafts().send(userId='me', body={ 'id': 's:7341000979429260348' }) –

Comment: What is the value of the To header in the draft?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo The e-mail addresses to be sent are already registered in the draft, I could not understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: Can you get the draft message resource and examine the to header?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I don't know how to do this. Can you show me the way?

Comment: Use https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/get

Comment: I'm getting the request body code via get. I try to paste it in the part in the Send section, but I still get an error. What do I write in the request body part of the send section? Can you contact me via e-mail? my e-mail address: sales@widresa.net